# Is there TCA group/db field equivalent in flux?

Tags: typo3, flux, fedext

Is there a possibility to add a field, which could contain relationship to multiple types of records ?

I need flux's equivalent for such TCA definition :

```
    'related_data_elements' => array(
        'exclude' => 1,
        'label' => 'Label',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'group',
            'internal_type' => 'db',
            'allowed' => 'tt_address_group, tt_address, tx_cal_event, tx_cal_category', 
            'size' => 10,
            'minitems' => 0,
            'maxitems' => 50,
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Flux 6.0.x there is the `group` type ViewHelper; the `allowed` attribute on this supports CSV lists of table names.

However, in Flux 7.0.0 and the current git masters, the `group` type has been removed and replaced by a `relation` field type. This new field type currently only supports single-table relations, but another type is up-and-coming which will solve that: the `multiRelation` field type (currently not committed).

The `multiRelation` field is the one you need - sorry to report that it is not yet finished, but keep an eye out - I expect it to be committed soon (at the very least before 6.2 LTS gets released).

Cheers,
Claus

Comment: Thank You very much Claus for these precisions. I've managed to made new fields based on the structure of `File` field. It works pretty well with current trunk. Also I made `flux` BE fields for DAM (for one project in 4.5LTS). If somebody needs, let me know, could share.